# How to print/detect the scancode of a pressed key in pygame?

Tags: python, dictionary, pygame

How to print/detect the scancode of a pressed key in pygame?

If I do this:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    print event
```

It prints out:

```
<Event(2-KeyDown {'scancode': 1, 'key': 115, 'unicode': u's', 'mod': 0})>
<Event(3-KeyUp {'scancode': 1, 'key': 115, 'mod': 0})>
```

but how can I get it to print out the scancode part? e.g. prints out `1` when I press `d`.

I tried this:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    print event["scancode"]
```

which throws a error message because is not really a dictionary data structure.

Comment: Did you look up the documentation for the `Event` object? It probably has a getter, or the field is public.

Comment: Have you tried: `event.scancode`? Based on: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16044380/6647217

Comment: It's a little hard to find, but here's the documentation for `pygame.KEYDOWN` and `pygame.KEYUP` events: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `event.scancode`?  The [documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) indicates that key press events have the following attributes:

- `key` is the integer ID
- `unicode` is the UNICODE string for the single character
- `scancode` is the platform specific key code

I'm guessing that `mod` is a bit-mask of OR-d bits.