# Detect keyboard presses in Python 3 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have tried all the ways I can find to detect keypresses in python on Raspberry Pi 3 but I can't get any to work. - I want it to be that when I press Up Arrow my Raspberry Pi robot will move forwards. Thanks

Edit - I known this seems like a duplicate as others but others were for windows or Linux, which worked on those platforms because it tried but it didn't work on raspberry pi.

Comment: you did not try all the ways or you'd have succeeded. Try looping over `sys.stdin.read(1)` in the console.

Comment: This post may be better suited be on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pygame to detect key presses ([see this post for more guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044229/how-to-get-keyboard-input-in-pygame)) and then set the program to run on start up when you want to test the program([see this post for more guidance](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4123/running-a-python-script-at-startup)) . alternatively you could use SSH into the RPi if it is a on a network and run the script