# how to write a code so that user can choose a item in list by hitting a button on keyboard

Tags: python-2.7, list

import random

print"Wellcome to the Mali Chef restaurant!!"

menu = ["Meal_1, Meal_2, Meal_3, Meal_4"]

print"On todays menu is:",menu

print "Choose which meal would you like to take: "

secure_random = random.SystemRandom()

print(secure_random.choice(menu))

How to write a code so that a user can choose meal by pushing a button on keyboard?

Comment: Why random ? Does the customer receive random food after pressing the same button ? Or do you want there to be 4 buttons or LIST and the customer chooses one of the meals (No. 1 - 4) ? What should be output from the function (text or number of the meal) ?

Comment: If it is a button on the KEYBOARD, use the `for event in pygame.event.get():` loop. There is an event for keypresses. Look at this for help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16044380/7313664