# How do i make python detect a key press?

Tags: python, pygame, keyboard

I want this code to say Hi when a button is pressed
I use replit.com or repl.it
It says as an  error:

```
File "main.py", line 18, in intro
if keyboard.KEY_DOWN("a"):
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I am trying to make a monoploy game on python but errors like this keep popping up

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import os
import random
import math
import pygame
from pygame.locals import * 
import sys
from sys import exit
import keyboard
from keyboard import *
window = pygame.init()
print("Wellcome to Math monopoply!!!\n")
time.sleep(1)
def intro():
  print("Hi")
  if keyboard.KEY_DOWN("a"):
    print("hi")
intro()
```

Comment: The error is pointing out that the `keyboard.KEY_DOWN` object is a string, not a function. So you cannot call it with "a" as an argument.

Comment: See if this question can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044229/how-to-get-keyboard-input-in-pygame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help

```
import pygame #Import pygame
import sys #
pygame.init() #Initialise it

window = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,800)) #Create a 1000x800 window

while True: #while loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: #if the user presses the 'X' button
            pygame.quit() #De= initialise pygame
            sys.exit() #Exit
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: #if a key is pressed down
            if event.key == pygame.K_a: 
                print("Hi")
```

You can read more about [pygame.event.get()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) here

Answer (score 1):

if a key is currently held down can be detected with `pygame.key.get_pressed()`. [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) returns a list with the state of each key. If a key is held down, the state for the key is `True`, otherwise `False`:

```py
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_a]:
    # [...]
```

The keyboard events (see [pygame.event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module) occur only once when the state of a key changes. The `KEYDOWN` event occurs once every time a key is pressed. You need and application loop and an event loop to handle the events:

```py
# application loop
run = True
while run:

    # event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a: 
                print("Hi")
```