# pygame not detecting keypresses

Tags: python, pygame, keypress, keydown, keyup

I've been trying to get pygame to detect keypresses so later on I can move a character around on the screen. I'm new to coding so I might just be missing something simple, but I can't figure out what's wrong with the code, should I switch to pygame.key.get_pressed() or something instead? thanks in advance.

```
running = True
while running: 
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    # set background
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    player(playerX, playerY)
    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        
# detecting key presses
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.type == pygame.K_LEFT:
            print("left")
        if event.type == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            print("right")
        if event.type == pygame.K_UP:
            print("up")
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.type == pygame.K_LEFT or event.type == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            print("stop")
        pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Possibly duplicate:  [How can I make a sprite move when key is held down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961563/how-can-i-make-a-sprite-move-when-key-is-held-down) and [How to get keyboard input in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044229/how-to-get-keyboard-input-in-pygame/64494842#64494842)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). You must evaluate the events in the event loop instead of the application loop.
If you want to determine if a certain key is pressed, the you've to verify if the event type is `pygame.KEYDOWN` (or `pygame.KEYUP` for button release) and if the `.key` attribute of the event is equal the key enumerator.

```py
running = True
while running: 
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    # set background
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    player(playerX, playerY)
    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        
    # INDENTATION
    #-->|
        # detecting key presses
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:  #<-- "key" instead of "type"
                print("left")
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT: #<-- "key" instead of "type"
                print("right")
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:    #<-- "key" instead of "type"
                print("up")
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT: #<-- "key" instead of "type"
                print("stop")
    #-->|
    # INDENTATION
```

---

However, I recommend to use `pygame.key.get_pressed()` instead of the `KEYDOWN` event.

The keyboard events (see [pygame.event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module) occur only once when the state of a key changes. The `KEYDOWN` event occurs once every time a key is pressed. `KEYUP` occurs once every time a key is released. Use the keyboard events for a single action or a step-by-step movement

[`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) returns a sequence with the state of each key. If a key is held down, the state for the key is `True`, otherwise `False`. Use [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) to evaluate the current state of a button and get continuous movement.

```py
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
velocity = 5

running = True
while running: 
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    playerX += (keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] - keys[pygame.K_LEFT]) * velocity
    playerY += (keys[pygame.K_DOWN] - keys[pygame.K_UP]) * velocity

    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    player(playerX, playerY)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to indent this part of your code to be *in* the `for` loop:

```
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.type == pygame.K_LEFT:
            print("left")
        if event.type == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            print("right")
        if event.type == pygame.K_UP:
            print("up")
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.type == pygame.K_LEFT or event.type == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            print("stop")
        pygame.display.update()
```

Otherwise, the `event` will always only be the last `event` from the `pygame.event.get()` list.

So basically, from

```
running = True
while running: 
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    # set background
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    player(playerX, playerY)
    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        
# detecting key presses
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.type == pygame.K_LEFT:
            print("left")
        if event.type == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            print("right")
        if event.type == pygame.K_UP:
            print("up")
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.type == pygame.K_LEFT or event.type == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            print("stop")
        pygame.display.update()
```

to:

```
running = True
while running: 
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    # set background
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    player(playerX, playerY)
    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                print("left")
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                print("right")
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                print("up")
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                print("stop")
            pygame.display.update()
```

*(Notice the `event.key`s I replaced part of your `event.type`s with.)*