# Pygame won't read any uppercase keys

Tags: pygame

As an example, when I try to input (through py.event.get()) the ^ (above the 6), the event reads the shift key, but not the six.  The same is true for capital letters and @, #, $, %, *, (, and ).  The code below is in a while loop.  It works for all the keys that don't require a shift.

```
for event in py.event.get():
    if event.type == py.KEYDOWN:
        keys = py.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[py.K_CARET]:
            print("^")
        if event.type == py.K_CARET:
            print("^")
```

Answer (score 0):

See [How to get keyboard input in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044229/how-to-get-keyboard-input-in-pygame/64494842#64494842)

[`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) returns a list with the state of all keyboard buttons. This is not intended to get the key of a keyboard event. The key that was pressed can be obtained from the **`key`** attribute (not `type`) of the [`pygame.event.Event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.Event) object. This also works for uppercase keys:

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        print(event.key, event.unicode)
```

If this doesn't work for you, this is not a general problem, it is related to your system.

Comment: Wow!  That does work.  I'm not sure what I'm getting with event.key, but the event.unicode does seem to return what I want:
Shift-a gives: 97 A
a gives: 97 a
Shift-6 gives: 54 ^.

Not sure what the 97 and 54 represent.  Also, I get 1073742049 each time.  That is a mystery.  But the event.unicode gives the keystroke I want.

Thank you very much, you really know your stuff.

Comment: I should add, the long integer only prints when I use shift.  If I type a lowercase letter, I don't get it.  The number is a little different if I hit Alt or Ctrl.  So I suspect it is a code for those keys.