# How to make a character and move it with collisisions?

Tags: python, pygame, collision, motion

I'm making a 2D game on replit and so far, I'm doing pretty well. My last question is about making the map.

Here's the code for the map:

```py
import pygame, sys

BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
SAND = (194, 176, 128)
GRASS = (124, 252, 0)
FOREST = (0, 100, 0)

TileColor = {'W': BLUE, 'S': SAND, 'G': GRASS, 'F': FOREST}

map1 = ["WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
        "WWWWWWWWWGGGWWWWWWWWWWW",
        "WWWWWGGGGGGGGGGGWWWWWWW", 
        "WWWWGGGGGFFFGGGGGGWWWWW",
        "WWWGGGGGFFFFFFGGGGGWWWW", 
        "WWWGGGGGGFFFFFGGGGGGWWW",
        "WWGGGGGGGGGFFGGGGGGGWWW", 
        "WWGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGWW",
        "WWGGGGGGSSSSSSSGGGGGGGW", 
        "WWGGGGSSSSSSSSSSGGGGGGW",
        "WGGGGGGGSSGGGGGGGGGGGSW", 
        "WGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGSSW",
        "WSGGGGGGGGFFGGGGGGGGSSW", 
        "WSSGGGGGGFFFGGGGGFFGGSW",
        "WSSGGGGGFFFFFFGGFFFFFGW", 
        "WSGGGGFFFFFFFFFFFFFFGGW",
        "WWGGGGGFFFFFFFFFFFFGGWW", 
        "WWGGGGGGGFFFFFFFFGGGWWW",
        "WWWWGGGGGGGGFFGGGGGWWWW", 
        "WWWWWWSSSSSGGGGSSSWWWWW",
        "WWWWWWWWWSSSSSSSSWWWWWW", 
        "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWSWWWWWWWW",
        "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW"
        ]

TILESIZE = 22
MAPWIDTH = 23
MAPHEIGHT = 23

pygame.init()
DISPLAY = pygame.display.set_mode((MAPWIDTH * TILESIZE, MAPHEIGHT * TILESIZE))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    for row in range(MAPHEIGHT):
        for col in range(MAPWIDTH):
            pygame.draw.rect(
                DISPLAY, TileColor[map1[row][col]],
                (col * TILESIZE, row * TILESIZE, TILESIZE, TILESIZE))

    pygame.display.update()
```

Which got me this:

[image: My Map]

Now I want to make a little person moving around when I press the arrow keys, and then I want to make it not be able to move onto to blue (water). Any suggestions on how I could do that?

Comment: Where do you want your character to collide with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character is represented by a row an column in the grid:

```py
character = [5, 11]
```

Use the keyboard events to change the position of the character (see [How to get keyboard input in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044229/how-to-get-keyboard-input-in-pygame/64494842#64494842)). Skip character movement if new character position is not on grass (`map1[c_row][c_col] == 'G'`):

```py
run = True
while run:
    c_col, c_row = character
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                c_col += 1  
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                c_col -= 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                c_row -= 1  
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                c_row += 1   

    if 0 <= c_col < MAPWIDTH and 0 <= c_row < MAPHEIGHT:
        if map1[c_row][c_col] == 'G':
            character = [c_col, c_row]
```

Draw a rectangle at the character's position:

```py
run = True
while run:
    # [...]

    pygame.draw.rect(
        DISPLAY, (255, 0, 0),
        (character[0] * TILESIZE, character[1] * TILESIZE, TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
```

---

Complete example:

[image]

```py
import pygame, sys

BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
SAND = (194, 176, 128)
GRASS = (124, 252, 0)
FOREST = (0, 100, 0)

TileColor = {'W': BLUE, 'S': SAND, 'G': GRASS, 'F': FOREST}

map1 = ["WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
        "WWWWWWWWWGGGWWWWWWWWWWW",
        "WWWWWGGGGGGGGGGGWWWWWWW", 
        "WWWWGGGGGFFFGGGGGGWWWWW",
        "WWWGGGGGFFFFFFGGGGGWWWW", 
        "WWWGGGGGGFFFFFGGGGGGWWW",
        "WWGGGGGGGGGFFGGGGGGGWWW", 
        "WWGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGWW",
        "WWGGGGGGSSSSSSSGGGGGGGW", 
        "WWGGGGSSSSSSSSSSGGGGGGW",
        "WGGGGGGGSSGGGGGGGGGGGSW", 
        "WGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGSSW",
        "WSGGGGGGGGFFGGGGGGGGSSW", 
        "WSSGGGGGGFFFGGGGGFFGGSW",
        "WSSGGGGGFFFFFFGGFFFFFGW", 
        "WSGGGGFFFFFFFFFFFFFFGGW",
        "WWGGGGGFFFFFFFFFFFFGGWW", 
        "WWGGGGGGGFFFFFFFFGGGWWW",
        "WWWWGGGGGGGGFFGGGGGWWWW", 
        "WWWWWWSSSSSGGGGSSSWWWWW",
        "WWWWWWWWWSSSSSSSSWWWWWW", 
        "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWSWWWWWWWW",
        "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW"
        ]

TILESIZE = 22
MAPWIDTH = 23
MAPHEIGHT = 23

pygame.init()
DISPLAY = pygame.display.set_mode((MAPWIDTH * TILESIZE, MAPHEIGHT * TILESIZE))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

character = [5, 11]

run = True
while run:
    c_col, c_row = character
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                c_col += 1  
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                c_col -= 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                c_row -= 1  
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                c_row += 1   

    if 0 <= c_col < MAPWIDTH and 0 <= c_row < MAPHEIGHT:
        if map1[c_row][c_col] == 'G':
            character = [c_col, c_row]            


    for row in range(MAPHEIGHT):
        for col in range(MAPWIDTH):
            pygame.draw.rect(
                DISPLAY, TileColor[map1[row][col]],
                (col * TILESIZE, row * TILESIZE, TILESIZE, TILESIZE))

    pygame.draw.rect(
        DISPLAY, (255, 0, 0),
        (character[0] * TILESIZE, character[1] * TILESIZE, TILESIZE, TILESIZE))

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(100)

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some nice starter code for PyGame

```py
import pygame as pg, sys
mainClock = pg.time.Clock()
pg.init()
WINDOWWIDTH = 600
WINDOWHEIGHT = 400
screen = pg.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))


class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.rect = pg.Rect(200, 0, 10, 10)
        self.velocity = pg.Vector2(0, 0)
        print(self.rect)

    def draw(self, screen):
        pg.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), self.rect)


player = Player()
while True:

    # Input
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            pg.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_LEFT:
                player.velocity.x = -5
            if event.key == pg.K_RIGHT:
                player.velocity.x = 5
            if event.key == pg.K_UP:
                player.velocity.y = -5
            if event.key == pg.K_DOWN:
                player.velocity.y = 5
        elif event.type == pg.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pg.K_LEFT:
                player.velocity.x = 0
            if event.key == pg.K_RIGHT:
                player.velocity.x = 0
            if event.key == pg.K_UP:
                player.velocity.y = 0
            if event.key == pg.K_DOWN:
                player.velocity.y = 0

    # Update
    player.rect.left += player.velocity.x
    player.rect.top += player.velocity.y

    # Draw
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    player.draw(screen)

    pg.display.update()
    mainClock.tick(40)
```

Last I'd like to mention two things:
I learned so much from this series by [DaFluffyPotato](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxRhvyZXd8I&list=PLX5fBCkxJmm1fPSqgn9gyR3qih8yYLvMj).
If you are coding a game for python, while PyGame has the largest community alternatives like [rubato](https://rubato.app/) and [pyglet](https://pyglet.org/) are objectively much better.

Just to show, the same code above is achievable in way fewer lines in rubato:

```py
import rubato as rb

rb.init()

main_scene = rb.Scene()

player = rb.GameObject(name="player", pos=rb.Display.center)
player.add(rb.Rectangle(color=rb.Color.red, width=100, height=100))
main_scene.add(player)

speed = 100


def main_update():
    if rb.Input.key_pressed("left"):
        player.pos.x -= speed * rb.Time.delta_time
    if rb.Input.key_pressed("right"):
        player.pos.x += speed * rb.Time.delta_time
    if rb.Input.key_pressed("up"):
        player.pos.y -= speed * rb.Time.delta_time
    if rb.Input.key_pressed("down"):
        player.pos.y += speed * rb.Time.delta_time


main_scene.update = main_update
rb.begin()
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you have to do is create a new python file and name it **player.py**, the next thing you should do is import player.py to the main file.

Now make sure you have imported Pygame to the **player.py** file

```
import pygame
```

Now lets create a class called "Player"(make SURE it has a CAPITAL "P")
and inside of this class create the function **init**

```
def __init__(self,ai_game):
        self.screen=ai_game.screen

        #this is the position of the player
        self.posX=0
        self.posY=0
```

The next thing you have to do is create a function that draws the player on the screen(after all what's the fun of a game without the player)

```
def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image,self.rect)
        # change the color to anything you want
        color = (255,0,0)

        #⚠️WARNING⚠️ self.posX and self.posY are JUST to make the player SEEM like it's moving but later if you want to add collisions then make SURE you create a RECT variable
 
        self.draw.rect(self.screen, color, pygame.Rect(30, 30, self.posX, self.posY))
```

The next thing to do is go back to your main python file and create a new function named check

now make sure in your main file to write this line of code:

```
player=Player()
```

now go back to your **for event in pygame......** and write all of this:

```
                       if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
                              if event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                                    player.posX+=1
                              elif event.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
                                    player.posX-=1
                              elif event.key==pygame.K_UP:
                                    player.posY-=1
                              elif event.key==pygame.K_DOWN:
                                    player.posY+=1
```

if you recieve any errors please give me the repl link and I will try to fix it!