# Why every key on keyboard in event.type in pygame has same id as the rest of keyboard

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to check if keyUp is pressed by event.loop in pygame, but when i click any other button on keyboard i get the same output with print(event.type) that every key has same id as pygame.KEYUP
Here is the code:

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP: print("key up")
```

Answer (score 0):

`KEYUP` down does not address the "up" key. It is the event that occurs when a key is released. You must check that the event type is `KEYDOWN` (key pressed) and the key is `K_UP`:

```py
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            print("key up")
```

Also see [How to get keyboard input in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044229/how-to-get-keyboard-input-in-pygame/64494842#64494842).

Answer (score 0):

Any key that gets pressed on the keyboard generates a keydown event. Any key that gets released generates a keyup event.

- If you want to know whether the 'up arrow' key got pressed, check for keydown on the K_UP key.
- If you want to know whether the 'up arrow' key got released, check for keyup on the K_UP key.
- If you want to know whether the 'down arrow' key got pressed, check for keydown on the K_DOWN key.
- If you want to know whether the 'down arrow' key got released, check for keyup on the K_DOWN key.