# I want to run if statements with events, that also use keyboard inputs to decide, and are placed inside a function but it don't work

Tags: python, function, if-statement, pygame

I'm trying to make a game using pygame and I want to use functions that contains events, but the if statements with events inside the function don't work when I call the function

The code goes like this

```
def tryy():
    print("this one will print")

    # I want these two to be able to run
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_2:
            print("but this won't")
        if event.key == pygame.K_3:
            print("this don't work too")
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            # I want it so that after 1 is press you can run the events inside the function "tryy" when the right key input is press for those events
            if event.key == pygame.K_1:
               tryy()

        pygame.display.update()
        
pygame.quit()
```

I was expecting that when I chose "1" for example would be the option to fight, then the function "tryy" would be called to give you two options (two different attacks), but it don't work.

can anyone help me on this pls. thanks

Comment: the "duplicate question"  wasn't even the same as my original question. Why is my question even set as duplicate??...

Comment: the "duplicate question" was about "How to get keyboard input in pygame?", mine was different from that. I just want to know why my events inside my functions don't work when I call the function..

Comment: You cannot handle an event "in" an event. See [How to get keyboard input in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044229/how-to-get-keyboard-input-in-pygame)

Answer (score 0):

You must call `tryy` in the event loop, but not in under the condition of another event. If you want to determine whether "2" or "3" was pressed after "1" was pressed, you must add a variable indicating that "1" was pressed. You must also pass the event object to the function:

```py
def tryy(event):
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_2:
            print("2")
        if event.key == pygame.K_3:
            print("3")

pressed_1 = False

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        if pressed_1:
            tryy(event)

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_1:
                pressed_1 = True
            else:
                pressed_1 = False
```

Answer (score -1):

The if statements work but event is not being fetched again inside the function so the `event.key` is set to `pygame.K_1` and the condition check fails at if statement.

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")

def tryy():
    print("this one will print")
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_1:
            print("this will print")
        if event.key == pygame.K_2:
            print("but this won't")
        if event.key == pygame.K_3:
            print("this don't work too")
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_1:
               tryy()

        pygame.display.update()
        
pygame.quit()
```

if you want a new event inside the function the