# Pygame Flappy Bird

Tags: python, pygame

```
# game variables
score = 0
gravity = 1
jump_height = 12
y_change = 0
jump = False
fps = 60
timer = pygame.time.Clock()
game_over = False
flying = False
run = True

# player x,y and obstacles
player_x = 50
player_y = 250
jump_count = 10

while run:
    # keyboard
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[pygame.K_w]:
        jump = True
    if jump:
        player_y -= jump_height
        jump_height -= y_velocity
```

Hello, this is my first time on StackOverflow, as well as it is my first 'big' programming project. I know the code is a complete mess, but I need help. So basically, I'm trying and failing to make Flappy Bird in Pygame. I need my bird ('player' in the code) to be able to jump, not once, but every time you press 'w'. For now, it lets you jump only once and then you fall, and the game stops when you touch either the floor or the obstacles. I'd be very thankful for some explanations as to what I should do, but I know it might be challenging to decipher my beginner code.

Comment: Review your variables, they are all initialized but some are set on conditions within the loop but not reset in the loop, e.g. `jump` or `active` (the latter may be intentional). So if you jump once, you always jump. This will decrement `jump_height` in each iteration until it becomes negative. Which in turn will affect `player_y`. Put `jump = False` somewhere in the while loop.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: 1. You have to use the keyboard events (`KEYDOWN`), instead of `pygame.key.get_pressed()` (see [How to get keyboard input in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044229/how-to-get-keyboard-input-in-pygame)). 2. Set `jump_height = 12` when the `KEYDOWN` event is detected. 3. `if jump_height <= 0: jump = False`